# What is the Pythonic Way of Saving a Class to a File and Adding Methods to it on Load

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a list of instances of a class that I save to a pickle file, they contain metadata for files.  At the moment the class includes methods that do things within the program, so essentially I'm saving a whole bunch of duplicate methods to a file so that when I load them into my program I can do stuff with the metadata.

This seems like a horrible way to do it for a lot of reasons, one is that the file is going to be bigger and will take longer to load in the index file, and two is that if anyone wanted to they could replace a function in the index file and that would get run by my program...

So I'm wondering what is the most pythonic way to index metadata and then deal with it when it's loaded into the program. Should I have a class that I pass the metadata to that has all the necessary methods?  Or is it possible to wrap the metadata class after it's loaded in?

I would prefer to be able to access the metadata and methods from one class e.g.

```py
m = MetaDataClass()

print(m.filename)  # test.txt
m.upload_to_dropbox()  # just an example method
```

Let me know if you need any more details.  Thanks

Comment: _if anyone wanted to they could replace a function in the index file and that would get run by my program_ This is a known vulnerability of pickle.  If you're really concerned, don't use pickle.

Comment: This is awfully abstract.  If we knew what you aretrying to accomplish (as opposed to the particular technique you are using to accomplish it), you'd get more useful answers.

Comment: "t the moment the class includes methods that do things within the program, so essentially I'm saving a whole bunch of duplicate methods to a file so that when I load them into my program I can do stuff with the metadata." no you aren't. each instance does not get a copy of a method.

Comment: Even if someone didn't change a method they could just add a `exec` call within the code. This is a vulnerability of reading code from a file. You can try to scan for malicious content but you can't get it all.

Comment: As @juanpa.arrivillaga said, `pickle` does not save the code for class methods in the the file, it just saves a reference to the module that contains the `class` definition. There's a third-party module named `dill` that supports actually saving `class` definitions in a pickle file—but you would only need to save one copy of it.

Comment: So is what I'm doing okay then?  It would be really convenient if it is :)